# calling class from webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

am accessing a class from my webservice as

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string fetchAbsentees(string date)
    {
        string data = string.Empty;

        StudentAttendances students = new StudentAttendances(date);

        SearchStudents fetchStudents =new SearchStudents(students);

            data = jsonSerialize.Serialize(fetchStudents);
        }
        return data; 
    }
```

when I execute this code am getting the values from the `StudentAttendance` class, I have `StudentId` property along with `attendancestatus`, `date` etc in the `StudentAttendance` class....

in the `SearchStudentClass` I have a constructor with one parameter(to accept the StudentId), my question is how can I get the `StudentId` alone from students and pass it to `SearchStudents`........can anyone help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of ids from students using Linq

```
students.Select(student => student.StudentId);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<YourIDType>`.  If that's what you're passing to `SearchStudents()`.

Above, you mention that `SearchStudents` accepts a single `StudentId`, so in that case you'd need to iterate over each of the students returned by `StudentAttendances(date)`.

I don't know what your `SearchStudents` class looks like, nor what is returned by `StudentAttendances(date)` but you could iterate over each of the students returned by the latter, pass it in to the former, and aggregate the results before serializing to JSON.